# Angular Promise<void>' is not assignable to type

Tags: angular, api, typescript

I am building Angular4 website using Contentful CMS API to retrieve data. 
The problem is I cannot assign the right types for the returned data even thought the console shows those types.

the Mock data:

```
export const NAMES: Page[] = content.getEntries({
    content_type: 'mainMenu'
}).then(function(response){
 response.items.forEach(element => {
   return element.fields;  
 })
});
```

Which is return via the console (If is used console.log ) :

```
Object { title: "About Aliens" }
Object { title: "Portfolio" }
Object { title: "Meet the team" }
Object { title: "Contact us" }
```

and the class I use to assign those data types :

```
export class Page {
  title: string;
}
```

I am new to Typescript and I want to know where I got wrong and I would appreciate it if someone guided me where I can go to master returning such data from any API.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

1. You are trying to assign a promise to an array, you have to do the assignment in the callback of the promise.
2. Your `then` call on the promise does not return anything, a call to `forEach` iterates over a collection but returns nothing. If you want to create/return something you could use `map` which creates a new collection based on the passed in predicate.
3. Use an arrow function for the promise callback so you have a reference to `this` should you need it.
4. There is no need to make Page a concrete type, use an interface instead so you can use casting. You only need a concrete type if you are going to add behavior but if its just a plain old object that is deserialized from json use an interface.

The fix:

```
export NAMES: IPage[]; // no assignment at this point
```

Execute getEntries from within some method.

```
content.getEntries({
    content_type: 'mainMenu'
}).then((response) => {
   NAMES = response.items.map(element => element as IPage);
});
```

**IPage**

```
export interface IPage {
  title: string;
}
```

Comment: OP wants to data to be type `Page`, so... `.map(element => Object.assign(new Page(), element.fields))` ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Make your page class an interface for type assertion without the need for instantiation, like so

```
export interface Page { title : string }
```